# Update copyright at bottom of page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking to update the copyright date from this [wordpress website](http://www.chronline.org/) to be current. At the bottom of the page it lists the copyright. I was told to check out footer.php but you can't find the string ' Center for Homicide Research © 2012. All Rights Reserved.' so I cannot edit it.

Comment: Is there any settings from the theme options from admin side ?

Comment: use theme editor to edit any theme file.  That code is in functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

go to wp-admin >> Go to Appearance >> editor >>> select functions.php Theme functions file

than find 2012. All reserve.

edit it and save it.